# changing between log and linear colorbar imshow matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib figure generated with imshow(), and I want to update it with new data and switch between a log and linear colorbar and normalization. I could just delete all the axes and start over but this is slow. I've figured out how to update the data and normalization, but can't switch between a log and a linear colorbar without deleting the colorbar.

This draws the initial image with a log colorbar:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(100, 100)
figure = plt.figure('test')
axes = figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
image = axes.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm())
colorbar = figure.colorbar(image)
figure.canvas.draw()
```

Then change the data:

```
data2 = 10000 * np.random.rand(5, 10)
rows, cols = np.shape(data2)
image.set_data(data2)
image.set_extent([-0.5, cols - 0.5, -0.5, rows - 0.5])  # is there a better way to do this?
image.autoscale()
figure.canvas.draw()
```

Then change the normalization and attempt to change the colorbar, but the ticks are in the wrong place, as if the colorbar is still log:

```
colorbar.locator = mpl.ticker.LinearLocator()
colorbar.formatter = mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter()
image.set_norm(mpl.colors.Normalize())
# colorbar.update_ticks() # doesn't change anything
figure.canvas.draw()
```

If I start with a linear colorbar (omit the norm argument in the first section), switching to a linear colorbar also doesn't work:

```
colorbar.locator = mpl.ticker.LogLocator()
colorbar.formatter = mpl.ticker.LogFormatterMathtext()
image.set_norm(mpl.colors.LogNorm())
figure.canvas.draw()
```